# How to prevent VSCode from focusing on the search bar when I press cmd-e

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have deep muscle memory from Sublime Text to do a partial search and replace by:

- copy the text I want to use as a replacement (cmd-c)
- search for the text I want to replace (cmd-e)
- go to the next occurrence (cmd-g)
- paste (cmd-v)
- repeat cmd-g, cmd-v as desired

This *almost* works in VSCode, except that pressing cmd-e moves focus to the search bar, so when I press cmd-v to paste, it pastes *in the search bar*, not *over top of the found text*.

Is there any setting (or other way) to prevent cmd-e from moving focus to the search bar? Or to make cmd-g move focus back to the file buffer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to very patient help and guidance from Brian Malehorn, I have a functioning solution.

Install the [macros extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros).

Add to user settings:

```
    "macros": {
        "findNextAndFocusText": [
            "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction",
            "closeFindWidget"
        ]
    }
```

Add to keybindings:

```
    {
        "key": "cmd+g",
        "command": "macros.findNextAndFocusText",
        "when": "editorFocus"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the keyboard shortcuts file by pressing Cmd-Shift-P and typing `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`
2. You can disable Cmd-E by adding this entry:

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+e",
    "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpen",
  },
```

To make Cmd-E open the search menu, add this entry:

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+e",
    "command": "actions.find"
  },
```

Finally, all of that might not be necessary. Alt-Cmd-F will open a "find and replace" menu that runs through your process of finding the next match and replacing it.

You may also want to check out the [Sublime Text Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings) extension. This will automatically set a bunch of shortcuts from Sublime Text to work in VSCode.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. Unfortunately, none of this quite works. I don't want to disable cmd+e. Switching cmd+e to actions.find still places the focus on the search bar when I type it. I want the focus to be in the input area, so that when I paste, it pastes over the found text. cmd+h hides the window in macOS, but I can remap that. I tried modifying the shortcut keys so that I can drive Find and Replace with familiar keyboard shortcuts (the defaults, shift+cmd+1 and F4 aren't exactly easy to use). But apparently I can't use cmd+v or cmd+g in their place. I am already using the Sublime Text Keymap...

Comment: ...extension, and it is generally excellent. It is only this one particular behavior that I can't get right. And it is one I use a lot.

Comment: I think it's going to be hard to replicate the exact behavior replace-then-disappear functionality from Sublime Text. I was wrong earlier when I said Cmd-H would run find & replace - instead, the keyboard shortcut is Alt-Cmd-F to find and replace. Or bind "editor.action.startFindReplaceAction" to another key you're more familiar with.

Comment: Yeah. The best workaround I've found is to hit the escape key as part of the sequence: cmd+e, cmd+g, esc, cmd+v, cmd+g, esc, cmd+v, etc. Perhaps I should file a feature request for a command to "dismiss the search bar". Then assuming you can attach multiple commands to a key (or macros?) I could hook it up cmd+g. Do you know where I would file such a feature request?

Comment: I'm still not sure why you can't use Alt-Cmd-F to find & replace instances - once you get used to it, it will be fewer keystrokes and also supports substitution. But if you want to dismiss the search bar, the command is called `closeFindWidget`, and if you want to run multiple command to a key, you're looking for the "macros" extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros

Comment: Thanks, Brian, for all your help!